# Group policy deployed printer: One duplicates?

Tags: group-policy, shared-printers

As a preface, no this doesn't have to do with Remote Desktop's Redirected printers at all.

I've deployed an HP printer (called \Manager\Picasso) under User Configuration in a Group Policy object. This is fine, works great, I can print ok.

The problem is that the printer is physically showing up twice, despite being listed only once in the policy. 
According to `HKCU\Printers\Connections` in the registry, it's supposed to only be there once as well.

Everything about these two printers (which is really just one) is identical, with the exception that one claims its' location to be `Spooler Internal` and the other to be `\Users\S-1-5-21-2824181156-3210474303-1020481702-500\Printers\^\^\manager^\Picasso` as shown below (viewed by displaying the object properties in Devices and Printers):
[image: Duplicate Printer properties]

My only guess is somehow this particular printer may be configured differently than the rest? It seems that this one gets duplicated because it has some sort of special queue or something.

Comment: As a side note, neither of the two other printers exhibits this behavior, a Brother and another HP printer.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I'm currently working on a similar issue.  I have seen some say that Universal Drivers for printers have had this effect but in my scenario this is not the case.

Comment: @Zombian No, I did end up adjusting the group policy to only apply the printer from the Users side, instead of on the Machine side (IIRC, memory a little fuzzy).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I think I just solved this.  HKCU\Printers\Connections showed one entry (even after deleting the printer).  The GPO is deploying via Machine.  I deleted the key in HKCU, restarted, and only get one printer.

Update: I cleaned up two other users on the PC, restarted again, and the key and duplicate printer is back.